# CodePipeline: Action configuration for action '2ndSource' contains unknown configuration 'PollForSourceChanges'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit, aws-codestar

There is AWS CodePipeline based on two Github source. Requirement is to restrict the pipeline auto trigger for primary source only. Found  [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-codepipeline-terraform-cicd-samples/blob/7d58aa2a669b3147f05d4992e90847271d8b0f9d/modules/codepipeline/main.tf#L38) snippet from terraform aws samples to disable auto trigger.

I tried the same but getting error (Tested with latest hashicorp/aws "4.57.1" version too) -

**Error: updating CodePipeline (xxxx): InvalidActionDeclarationException: Action configuration for action '2ndSource' contains unknown configuration 'PollForSourceChanges'**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.57.1"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_codepipeline" "service" {
  name     = "${var.environment}-${var.name}"
  role_arn = var.codepipeline_role_arn

  artifact_store {
    location = "${var.aws_s3_bucket_id}"
    type     = "S3"
  }

  stage {
    name = "Source"
    action {
      name             = "Source"
      category         = "Source"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeStarSourceConnection"
      version          = "1"
      output_artifacts = ["source"]

      configuration = {
        ConnectionArn    = var.codestarconn_role_arn
        FullRepositoryId = var.source_location
        BranchName       = var.source_version
      }
      run_order = "1"
    }

    action {
      name             = "2ndSource"
      category         = "Source"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeStarSourceConnection"
      version         = "1"
      output_artifacts = ["source2"]

      configuration = {
        ConnectionArn    = var.codestarconn_role_arn
        FullRepositoryId = var.deploy_repo
        BranchName       = var.deploy_branch
        PollForSourceChanges = "false" // ---->> Throwing error
      }
      run_order = "2"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PollForSourceChanges` is used for AWS Source actions such as S3, CodeCommit. For Github, Bitbucket, Github Enterprise we use CodeStar Connection and you can disable the auto trigger by configuring the parameter `DetectChanges` as `false`. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodestarConnectionSource.html#action-reference-CodestarConnectionSource-config) are the full list of Configuration parameters for CodeStar Connection source action.

Answer (score 0):

After a lots of googling...found `DetectChanges = "false"`. It suffice my requirement.